# Rails + Carrierwave + facebook like + amazon s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, carrierwave

Im trying to set a like button in my products page, i want it to show the image of the product when someone likes it, im sure thats with the og:image metatag but when i yield my metatag i get this

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://amelias3.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/product/image/21/prod_pAERO1-11302691t386x450.jpg/">
```

instead of this

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://amelias3.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/product/image/21/prod_pAERO1-11302691t386x450.jpg">
```

the s3 url with the last backslash gives an access denied error, can someone has any idea why?

Comment: are you sure you are setting up the url correctly ?

Comment: well in my html i write it without the backslash, and when it renders it renders with the backslash

Comment: can you share code for rendering . In s3 properties, the link is stored without backslash . So,I am pretty sure, there is error at your code end.

Comment: Is it just me or are those URLs identical? 

Did you try using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to parse your URL?